# GAE full text search with "did you mean" feature

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

Is there any plan to include a "did you mean" feature in the Google App Engine Full Text Search API? It would be very powerful to have a default way of testing full text queries. For example the query "barcak obama" would generate: "Did you mean: barack obama ?" And it would be good to have the feature being able to simultaneously handle many different languages.

Comment: If you make a feature request for this I will star it. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request

Comment: Thanks. I have now posted this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7197

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time (but who knows what the future will bring), you would have to implement something on top of it yourself.

One way to get native support is file a feature request and get enough people vote for it. This will help to set the right priorities.

Comment: I just posted a feature request: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7197 

Without such feature developers would have to reinvent the 'wheel' again and again, and hardly any developer being able to implement as good version as Google.

Comment: I agree, it's nice when a platform handles common use cases. Thanks for filing the feature request.